# Very basic, method within a method in java

Tags: java, methods

This is a very basic Java question and I feel like I'm gonna smack myself after getting the answer, but I'm currently working on a project and the instructions are to add this method: Write a method called +createWelcomeMessage(userName:String)String[It is also underlined so it is static]. It should include a user-entered name and let the user know what the purpose of the program is. This is what I got:

```
public static String createWelcomeMessage(String UserName)
{
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String strUserName;  // to get user's name
String strWelcome;   //listed as the return in method name

System.out.print("\nPlease enter your name: ");
strUserName=kb.nextLine();

System.out.println("Hello" + strUserName + " the purpose of this project is...");


return strWelcome;
}  //end createWelcomeMessage(string)
```

The question is, what do I do with the string "strWelcome". Or is it just to use in the main method to recall this method. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't sound as though you've transcribed the task correctly. Surely the *purpose of the program* is to be supplied as a parameter, and the username is to be returned?

Comment: And there is no 'method within a method' here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should return something. As per your code, you have not initialized `strWelcome`. Maybe you are supposed to return the whole message back to be printed out? 
So in your `createWelcomeMessage(String userName)` you would initialize it as so:

```
strWelcome = "Hello" + strUserName + " the purpose of this project is...";
```

Then return as you have:

```
return strWelcome;
```

Then where you would call it to print it:

```
System.out.println(createWelcomeMessage(<put username here>));
```

or just set it to another string

```
String str = createWelcomeMessage(<put username here>);
```

Then print it:

```
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: I can't upvote, I don't have enough rep. Lol. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`strWelcome`, I beleive is your welcome message. So you want something like this.

```
strWelcome = "Hello" + strUserName + " the purpose of this project is..."

return strWelcome;
```

Then outside the loop:

```
System.out.println(strWelcome);
```

If you put the `System.out.println(strWelcome);` inside the lood, it would defeat the purpose if having a `String` value returned. You then would just have the method signature return `void`

Answer (score 0):

The first steps to do with a challenge is **break it down piece by piece**. Here's your question:

**Write a method called `createWelcomeMessage(userName:String)` (String also underlined so it is static). It should include a user-entered name and let the user know what the purpose of the program is**

**Step 1:**

Lets's create a method called `createWelcomeMessage`

```
public void createWelcomeMessage()
```

This is a basic definition. Don't worry we will modify it according to our needs.

**Step 2:**

**Should include a user entered name**. Hmmm. Let's do it. Take the userName as an argument to the method.

```
public void createWelcomeMessage(String userName)
{

}
```

**Step 3:**

It should **tell the user what the purpose of the program is**. Alright, lets go ahead an tell him:

```
public void createWelcomeMessage(String userName)
{
System.out.println("Hello"+userName+" ..! The purpose of this program is..");
}
```

Hmmm. I think it gets the job done. But wait, **lets modify** the code a little bit:

```
public void createWelcomeMessage(String userName)
{
  String welcomeMessage;
  welcomeMessage = "Hello"+userName+" ..! The purpose of this program is..");
}
```

Now that we have set the welcome message, lets show it to the user. How, you ask. Lets just say, we will **return the message to the user using a simple return**.

```
public void createWelcomeMessage(String userName)
{
  String welcomeMessage;
  welcomeMessage = "Hello"+userName+" ..! The purpose of this program is..");
  return welcomeMessage;
}
```

To **return the `welcomeMessage`** , of type String , modify the return type of the method to:

```
public String createWelcomeMessage(String userName)
{
  String welcomeMessage;
  welcomeMessage = "Hello"+userName+" ..! The purpose of this program is..");
  return welcomeMessage;
}
```

Since you said the **method must be static**, add the keyword static to the method.

```
public static String createWelcomeMessage(String userName)
{
  String welcomeMessage;
  welcomeMessage = "Hello"+userName+" ..! The purpose of this program is..");
  return welcomeMessage;
}
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

package com.example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample {
    public static String createWelcomeMessage(String UserName)
    {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String strUserName;  // to get user's name
    String strWelcome = UserName;   //listed as the return in method name

```
System.out.print("\nPlease enter your name: ");
strUserName=kb.nextLine();

System.out.println("Hello " + strUserName + " the purpose of this project is...");


return strWelcome;
}  //end createWelcomeMessage(string)
public static void main(String[] args){
    String result = Sample.createWelcomeMessage("Sample");
    System.out.println("Value:"+result);
}
```

}

Output:
Please enter your name: test
Hello test the purpose of this project is...
Value:Sample